# How to goto an loop start while in if statement using bash?

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement

**What we have:**

```
m=1
while [[ $m -le 5 ]]
do
curl --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 5 -X POST https://example.com/create >> test.txt
if [ -s test.txt ]
then
    echo "Empty file"
    ##"GO TO BEGIN OF LOOP"##
else
    echo "All fine"
fi

...

done
```

We'd like to check if `test.txt` is empty. If it is we need to go to the begin of our loop.

*I am new to stackoverflow. Feel free to comment so that I can improve myself in how to ask questions.*

Comment: use `continue`  ...

Comment: .. and remember to have an exit condition to break on, to avoid infinite loop

Comment: Thx alot, `continue` works great.

Answer (score 0):

```
m=1
while [[ $m -le 5 ]]
do
curl --connect-timeout 5 --max-time 5 -X POST https://example.com/create >> test.txt
if [ -s test.txt ]
then
    echo "Empty file."
    continue
else
    echo "All fine."
fi

...

done
```

Comment: Whilst this code snippet is welcome, and may provide some help, it would be [greatly improved if it included an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of *how* and *why* this solves the problem. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.